# value error string can not be converted to float?

Tags: python, list, replace, strip

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Field,Item
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst,MapCompose

def get_price(txt):

    value = txt.replace('1.359,20','1.359')
    value = txt.replace(',','.')
    value = txt.strip('1.499,00')
    value = txt.strip('R$')
    float(value)

class MultilaserItem(scrapy.Item):
\# define the fields for your item here like:
\# name = scrapy.Field()
title = Field(output_process=TakeFirst())
price = Field(input_processor=MapCompose(get_price),output_processor=TakeFirst())
\#installment = Field(output_process=TakeFirst())
```

your text when i do this `value = txt.replace(',','.')`
should it not replace the value in `14,90` to `14.90`? but i am stuck with error

```
ValueError: Error with input processor MapCompose: field='price' value=\['R$ 14,90'\] error='ValueError: Error in                MapCompose with \<function get_price at 0x7fa825ee0b80\> value=\['R$ 14,90'\] error='ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 14,90
```

Comment: also, your `get_price` function isn't returning anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code above only applies the last operation `value = txt.strip('R$')` that results with " 14,90" which is not a valid floating point number and raises a value error.

To perform multiple operations on a string then need to reassign the variable after each operation.

Try a function like the following to get the price from a string input:

```
def get_price(txt):
    txt = txt.replace(',','.')
    value = txt.strip('R$')
    return float(value)

price = get_price("R$ 14,90") 
print(f"{price:.2f}")
```

**Output:**

```
14.90
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = txt.replace('1.359,20','1.359')
value = txt.replace(',','.')
value = txt.strip('1.499,00')
value = txt.strip('R$')
```

These replacements use the original value of `txt`, so they are not cumulative.  Each one undoes the previous one.  So you end up with only the final replacement of `strip('R$')`.  The first three are discarded.